# Как передать встроенный тип в функцию по ссылке в C#

Tags: c#

Как передать встроенный тип в функцию по ссылке в C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для передачи встроенного типа по ссылке необходимо объявить его с модификатором ref. Например.

```
class SomeClass 
 {
    public void refPramFunc(ref int refParam) {
    // Код функции
    }
 }
```